# python multiplication {how to do it with a dic ?}

Tags: python

**Here's what im trying to do** :

name of snack then price , the print the name ,quantity and total price... is it possible to link the name with price then i could only multiply the price ? i tried to do function but i ended up missing with code

** problems **:

if i print the order it shows all the items in food_price with changing the value of the selected item...so it's actually not multiplying the price

**e.g**:
Type in an Order to add to add: Hot dog
How many would you like : 2

then when i print the order it shows me the whole list:

Buttered Popcorn L : 8

Buttered Popcorn M : 7

Peanut M&M's : 3.1

Hot dog : 2( 2 became the value "price" of the hot dog)

```
    Please choose your order  :


 |#| **Food**         |Size       |Calories  |     Price |
 =========================================================
   Buttered Popcorn L    Large         1200     8$
   Buttered Popcorn M    Medium         910     7$
   Buttered Popcorn S    Small          650     5$
   Hot dog               Medium             305     5$

"""
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you put in your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Might I suggest you [**read the Python Style Guide**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)? Applying it to your code makes it easier for us to read it, thereby you will get more answers and better ones quickly. On another note, we like to help with *specific* **problems** that you encounter. A problem is something you tried and doesn't work, not something you need. Try describing what you're struggling/stuck with to help us all protect the endangered species of crystal balls. Thank you.

Comment: What does the question have to do with multiplication?

Comment: am i the only one not seeing "snickers" there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your food to be accessible by code, you should have it organised with the code as the key, and the rest of the data as the value, e.g.

```
foods = { 1 : ("Snickers", "One size", 1200, 100) }
```

Then you can do:

```
for code, (name, size, calories, cents) in foods.iteritems():
    print "%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s " % (code, name, size, calories, cents)
```

Which will print out all of the options.

Even better, you can then store the orders in a number of ways:

```
orders = []
orders.append((code, number))
```

or

```
orders = {}
orders[code] = number
```

Then you can access the data in the original `food` `dict`.

Comment: orders = {}
orders[code] = number
worked better !! thanks so much :D